# Strange UITableView Selection behavior, selection only after long tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've run into a strange UITableViewController behavior.

For explanation:

I have a quite simple UITableView. Just 3 Default Cells with a Text. 
But it behaves like shown in the GIF below. (The GIF is a little bit slower than reality)

Normal "short" taps are neither highlight or select something. 
A longer press highlights the cell until released. 
And only after a long long tap the cell is selected.

I have no idea what can cause these issue and I don't know where to search.

Some Code: [TableViewController + DataSource](http://pastebin.com/ntekN95C)

Have anyone a hint where to start debugging ?

[image: Simple Table]

[image: TableViewControllerAttributes]

[image: ViewAttributes]

[image: ViewHierachie]

Answer (score 2):

You've probably set up a tap gesture recognizer somewhere else in the view hierarchy which is eating your tap gestures.

Since you're presenting a plain vanilla table view, you really don't want to do that.

*(apologies in advance to the community -- this should've been a comment but I can't comment because I've got a bad reputation)*

Comment: No TapGestureRecognizer in the whole project, that was my first thought, too.

Comment: Your app consists of just 1 root view controller -- your table view?

First thing I would do is see if you accidentally somehow added a gesture recognizer to a view in your xib / storyboard.

Second, add a screen grab to your original post of both your TableView and TableViewController xib / storyboard settings.

Comment: It's a little bit complex, my app is based on the Coordinator principle. But at least the Coordinators results in a single ViewController which holds  the tableView. There are no accidentally added Gesture Recognizers in XIB. Which XIB-Settings do you mean ?

Comment: Show the settings from the Attributes Inspector for the TableView and your TableViewController. Or if you're building it all up from scratch, post the setup code in your loadView() method.

Comment: The ViewController is in the Pastebin above, images are edited

Answer (score 0):

I've got it ;) 
I've found a TapGestureRecognizer within a self written sub framework.
After commenting this out it works well. 
So I have to search the issue within my sub framework.

A lot of thanks to you, without your hint I never thought about it again

Comment: You can also `gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false` in case you need that gesture recognizer